# Remove curly brackets from string

Tags: php, regex

I've found many examples on the internet, but still can't find a solution for this.
I got a PHP page that needs to parse a HTML+JS page and needs to remove everything included between { } and also the brackets itself.
The point is that the content of the brackets must be [A-Za-z0-9_] and not anything else (like i did so far).

This is my current replace:

```
$this->content = preg_replace("/\{((?:[^{}]++|\{(?1)\})++)\}/", "", $this->content);
```

So far now this works pretty good, the point is that doesn't search for right contents between brackets and removes them no matter what's inside (atm it's removing JS functions from the content of the page that is parsing).

What do I've to modify to add that kind of character restriction to the content of the reg-ex?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what exactly your current version does/how it works?

Comment: Thanks to you all guys. This solved the issue: $this->content = preg_replace("/\{[a-zA-Z0-9_]+?\}/", "", $this->content);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this pattern:

```
\{[a-zA-Z0-9_]+?\}
```

Better to use lazy quantification with `?` sign at the end of repetitions number.

Comment: @JohannesH. Thanks, I'm aware of greediness. However, the character class will never match a closing bracket `}`.

Comment: As the one suggested by @Marius, it removes all the content of the page but HTML comments. $this->content = preg_replace("\{[a-zA-Z0-9_]+?\}", "", $this->content);

Comment: @MariusSchulz Yes, see comment on your answer. Was to quick on this ;)

Comment: Victor: As discussed in the above comments, you don't need a lazy quantifier here.

Comment: @DarioEmerson There is no reason for it to do so... Mind to provide the actual string you'Re working with in some pastebin?

Comment: @DarioEmerson Oh. Well, ALMOST no reason. YOu still have to put some delimiters around this... currently you're using `\}` as your delimiter, so it'S not part fo the expresison anymore. use this: `$this->content = preg_replace('/\{[a-zA-Z0-9_]+?\}/', '', $this->content);`

Answer (score 1):

The pattern to match those brace substrings is pretty simple:

```
\{[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\}
```

It escapes `{` and `}` which might otherwise be treated as parts of a quantifier (like e.g. `{3}`). Note that, depending on the programming language, you might have to double-escape the braces (`\\{[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\}`) so that the backslashes themselves are escaped.

Comment: I've already tried this:
$this->content = preg_replace("\{[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\}", "", $this->content);
And it removed all the content of the page, but HTML comments..

Comment: ALmost. Make that innermost expression non-greedy, otherwise it will remove anything between the first `{`and last `}`.

Comment: @JohannesH. Nope, it won't. I didn't use `.*`, and `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` won't consume a `}`.

Comment: Erm... yes, apparently you'Re right. SOrry, my fault.

Comment: @JohannesH. The common mistake people make is to use `.*` like this: `\{.*\}`, in which case you're totally right. That expression consumes way too many characters because the dot (`.`) pretty much matches anything.

Comment: I got this error from PHP: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: @DarioEmerson If I recall correctly, you have to escape your backslashes in PHP strings, like this: `\\{[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\}`

Comment: @DarioEmerson See my comment on the other answer: you're actually not providing any delimiters. YOu have to wrap the expressions given here and in the other answer in any char that's not part of the expression (usually `/`or `#`is used)

Answer (score 1):

`A-Za-z0-9_` can be represented as `\w` in regex.

So, if your brackets needs to contain at least a character inside, then the regex will be

```
\{\w+\}
```

If you think there can be empty, for example `{}` then you can use

```
\{\w*\}
```

If you want to allow space as well, then it will be

```
\{[\w\s]+\}
```